# Scroll controlling page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

this is quite difficult to explain, but I am looking for a browsers scrollbar to control a sites content.  A good example of what I am after can be seen [here](http://melaniedaveid.com/)  So as you can see, when you get to the about section, to scroll no longer controls the page but the content within that section.  I have looked at the code but it is not that reabible.

Starting from scratch, what would be the best way to achieve this type of effect?  I have set up a little [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47yqopt5/2/) which could be used for testing.  It just contains a basic section with quite a lot of content.

```
<section id="hero" class="vertical-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>
                    Some Title
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>
                "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
                </p>
                 <p>
                "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

It also has a portfolio slider section and it would be ideal if it could also work with the vertical slides.

Thanks for the input

Comment: Its hard to answer this question without building a very large demo. When things are `postition:fixed;` they won't move on the screen while the body scrolls. Things that aren't `position:fixed;`, will. So that website fixes the position of some element, while you continue scrolling the body of the page, and times changing these styles with your arrival at different sections of the page

Comment: You can see how a website works by inspecting their code in the browser Inspector. For example, in the page you linked, the "About" section contains two divs each occupying 50% of the screen. The left one has `position:fixed` and the right one `position:relative`, giving the illusion that you're only scrolling through the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, it will be as simple as this (you'll need firefox, safari or chrome with a flag enabled for it to work now)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.sticky-titles {} .sticky-titles .pane {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100wh;
  display: flex;
}
.pane-half {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
}
.pane .right {
  min-height: 150vh;
}
.pane .left {
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.pane:nth-child(odd) .left {
  background: tomato;
}
.pane:nth-child(even) .left {
  background: #333;
  color: #CCC;
}
.pane:nth-child(odd) .right {
  background: #AFA;
}
.pane:nth-child(even) .right {
  background: #CCC;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky-titles">
  <div class="pane">
    <div class="left pane-half">
      <h2>#1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="right pane-half">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dictum interdum pellentesque. Vivamus dictum eleifend dui, a faucibus enim. Aenean iaculis hendrerit accumsan. Etiam non purus et neque ornare aliquet. Morbi bibendum libero vehicula
        arcu tristique, ac lacinia nisl faucibus. Phasellus tempor, velit id convallis fringilla, mauris ante tempor risus, ut cursus turpis nibh non eros. Integer quis quam ut felis hendrerit laoreet. Aenean pulvinar accumsan purus. Sed posuere arcu
        nunc, non aliquam quam bibendum id. Aenean nec massa sed purus varius tempus. Vivamus vitae neque rhoncus, accumsan magna ac, ullamcorper risus. Nam non ligula id ligula congue tristique. Phasellus tristique diam a lectus feugiat pretium. Aliquam
        ex magna, convallis nec mollis eget, lacinia dignissim purus. Etiam consectetur sit amet mauris quis pulvinar.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pane">
    <div class="left pane-half">
      <h2>#2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="right pane-half">
      <p>
        Fusce consequat et sem a vestibulum. Donec dictum molestie nibh, ac ullamcorper justo sodales quis. Aliquam odio libero, efficitur vel ante non, dapibus viverra dui. Duis sollicitudin imperdiet nunc sed pretium. Duis sed elementum felis. Sed commodo hendrerit
        eros, vel consequat ipsum iaculis sit amet. Fusce tristique nisl ut felis tincidunt, vel dignissim purus mattis.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pane">
    <div class="left pane-half">
      <h2>#3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="right pane-half">
      <p>
        Pellentesque cursus dapibus eros, sit amet aliquet felis bibendum nec. Duis pretium velit a enim lobortis, sit amet dignissim massa ultricies. Phasellus convallis erat tempus mi porta efficitur. Vivamus hendrerit lacus nunc, ac consectetur nulla auctor
        non. Duis quis ante nec est pharetra efficitur. Sed ultricies, metus sit amet porta porttitor, neque nulla suscipit dolor, et placerat ligula arcu id diam. Sed semper, neque blandit fermentum bibendum, nunc libero pellentesque elit, luctus tempor
        risus purus eu felis. Etiam leo arcu, egestas ut felis ut, rhoncus ultricies nulla. Nulla facilisi. Integer a nulla ligula. Phasellus porttitor orci a neque posuere pellentesque. Curabitur quam lacus, fermentum at eleifend eu, dapibus quis felis.
        Sed rutrum eget mauris sed porta. Mauris porttitor placerat mi, et cursus lectus commodo consectetur. Quisque tincidunt aliquam massa vel sagittis. Duis a sem tempus, cursus lectus sed, venenatis orci.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At the moment it can't be used in many places, but as people want it more and more, browser vendors are sure to pick it up. You can keep and eye on the support [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-sticky)

Answer (score 1):

> when you get to the about section, to scroll no longer controls the
>   page but the content within that section.

Alternatively, the scroll *does* still control the page, but the left hand panel has `position: fixed` applied to it dynamically until the window's scroll bar is scrolled down far enough - after which point the `position: fixed` style is removed and the left-hand panel has a `margin-top` applied to it instead.

> Starting from scratch, what would be the best way to achieve this type
>   of effect?

1. Track the vertical position of the window scrollbar via a scroll event listener;
2. When the scrollbar reaches a certain y-coordinate, dynamically apply  `position: fixed; top: 0;` to the left-hand panel;
3. When the scrollbar reaches a second (lower) y-coordinate, remove the `position` style declaration and dynamically apply a `margin-top` style declaration;
4. Ensure that when the page is being scrolled up, the process happens in reverse: first the `margin-top` is applied, then removed and replaced with the `position` style declaration, then, finally, the latter is removed as well.